# Rust and JSON serialization

Tags: json, serialization, rust

If the JSON object is missing some fields, the `decode` function throws an exception. For example:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
enum MessageType {
    PING,
    PONG,
    OPT,
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
pub struct JMessage {
    msg_type: String,
    mtype: MessageType,
}

fn main() {
    let result3 = json::decode::<JMessage>(r#"{"msg_type":"TEST"}"#);
    println!("{:?}", result3);
    // this will print `Err(MissingFieldError("mtype"))`

    let result = json::decode::<JMessage>(r#"{"msg_type":"TEST", "mtype":"PING"}"#);
    println!("{:?}", &result);
    // This will print Ok(JMessage { msg_type: "TEST", mtype: PING })

    let result2 = Json::from_str(r#"{"msg_type":"TEST", "mtype":"PING"}"#).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", &result2);
    // this will print Object({"msg_type": String("TEST"), "mtype": String("PING")})
}
```

1. Is there a way to specify that some fields in a struct are optional?
2. Why does the function `from_str` not serialize `mtype` as an enum?

Comment: Please ask [only one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). Pick one and you can ask the other one as a follow up question.

Comment: I edited your question to use "raw string literals". Those greatly improve readability when dealing with these kinds of strings. [More details](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#raw-string-literals)

Comment: Serde ignores default fields, cf. https://erickt.github.io/blog/2016/02/26/serde-0-dot-7/

Answer (score 3):

1. No, there is no such way. For that, you need to use [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde). Serde also has lots of other features, but unfortunately it is not as easy to use as rustc_serialize on stable Rust.
2. Well, how should it? `Json::from_str` returns a JSON AST, which consists of maps, arrays, strings, numbers and other JSON types. It simply cannot contain values of your enum. And also there is no way to indicate that you want some other type instead of string, naturally.

Comment: In some other languages, you can provide to_json() and from_json() methods so objects can intelligently serialize themselves, and on unpacking, you can restore the correct type if you encoded it as part of the JSON data (via an ugly magic field your code looks for).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first question, you can use `Option`. For example:

```
pub struct JMessage {
    msg_type: Option<String>,
    mtype: MessageType,
}
```

Which [defaults to `None`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/16971) if the field does not exist.